# measure if some binary events happen in random or are correlated

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation, stochastic-processes, binary-data, randomness

I have thousands of binary processes of uneven length like those below:

```
x0 = [(0,0), (10,0), (12,1), (20,1), (30,1), (32,0]
x1 = [(0,0), (5,0), (11,0), (27,1), (32,0), (62,1), (71,0)]
x2 = [(0,1), (3,1), (19,1), (37,0)]
x3 = [(0,0), (13,0), (18,1), (27,1), (29,1), (34,1), (38,1), (47,1), (52,0), (55,1)]
```

The first element in each tuple is the time and the second element is if an event happens.

I need some statistical tests to evaluate if the event (second tuple element=1) happens randomly or somehow correlates with the past observations.

Can you please give me some hints on which family of statistical methods could help?

Comment: This is all very abstract. Can you describe your use case in english? What does this processes represent? Questions with some interesting context tends to generate more involvement!

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly your set up and your question. 
You want to know if for instance $x_3$ is independent of $x_2$ or if in each $x_i$ the observations are independent ? 
Would you have some example of such process to better understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting angle from information theory. Randomness of data has several applications in that fiield. A totally random binary series for example cannot be compressed. (A very predictable series can be.)

One example of such a test for randomness of a binary serues can be found here [Using Information Theory Approach to Randomness Testing](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0504006).

One might use and AND operator on two or more series to see if a combination of these series are less random.

I would be interested in the application domain.